# Vue.js and router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I need to use the router object inside a custom method but i keep getting an undefined error

I have registered the router in my App.vue `import router from './router'` and the router works when routing

Now, i have created an auth.js file to manage user status from a jwt token.

```
/* global localStorage */

import User from '@/models/User'

import * as MutationTypes from './mutation_types'

import router from '@/router'


const state = {
  user: User.from(localStorage.token),
  layout: 'home-layout'
}

const getters = {
  currentUser (state) {
    return state.user
  },
  layout (state) {
    return state.layout
  }
}

const mutations = {
  [MutationTypes.LOGIN] (state) {

    state.user = User.from(localStorage.token)
    console.log(state.user)
    if(!state.user.role){

        state.layout = 'home-layout'
    } else if (state.user.role==='USER'){
        console.log('sono utente')
        state.layout = 'home-layout'
    } else if (state.user.role==='ADMIN'){
        console.log('sono admin')
      state.layout = 'admin-layout'
      router.replace(route.query.redirect || "/admin");

    }

  },
  [MutationTypes.LOGOUT] (state) {
    state.user = null
    state.layout = 'home-layout'
  },
  SET_LAYOUT (state, payload) {
    state.layout = payload
  }
}

const actions = {
  login ({ commit }) {
    commit(MutationTypes.LOGIN)
  },

  logout ({ commit }) {
    commit(MutationTypes.LOGOUT)
  }

}

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
  router
}
```

this is the router/index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from '@/views/Home'
import Contacts from '@/views/Contacts'
import About from '@/views/About'
import Dashboard from '@/views/admin/Dashboard'
import ObjectList from '@/components/ObjectList'
import Register from '@/views/Register'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  linkExactActiveClass: 'active', // active class for *exact* links.
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/contacts',
      name: 'contacts',
      component: Contacts
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register
    },
    {
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    ...
  ]
})
```

so when i need to check the current user status i call the LOGIN action but i keep getting that `this.$router` is undefined, but it should be globally declared

what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Show the import part, and router file. Basically all the code that is involved.

Comment: thanks, added the whole code

Comment: I should expect it to work without router instead of router. But wat happens if you export a const instead of the default export const router = new Router...
And the import: import {router} from '@/router'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this` is not what you think it is.

```
import router from './router' //add correct path

const mutations = {
  [MutationTypes.LOGIN] (state) {

    state.user = User.from(localStorage.token)
    if(!state.user.role){

        state.layout = 'home-layout'
    } else if (state.user.role==='USER'){

        state.layout = 'home-layout'
    } else if (state.user.role==='ADMIN'){

      state.layout = 'admin-layout'
-     this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || "/admin");   //delete
+     router.replace(router.currentRoute.query.redirect || "/admin"); // add

    }

  },
  [MutationTypes.LOGOUT] (state) {
    state.user = null
    state.layout = 'home-layout'
  },
  SET_LAYOUT (state, payload) {
    state.layout = payload
  }
}
```

Comment: if i try this way, i lose the $route function

Comment: Right try `router.currentRoute`